# ¿En ocasiones debe usarse coma antes de "y"?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, conjunciones

Recientemente me corrigieron informándome de que si un listado tiene más de tres elementos debe colocarse una coma antes de la "y".

Ejemplo con 3 elementos:

> Hay tres sabores: chocolate, vainilla y fresa.

Ejemplo con más de 3 elementos:

> Tengo cinco crayones: rojo, verde, azul, amarillo, y naranja.

Esto me parece un poco raro, pero no encuentro nada que directamente afirme o niegue esta "regla".  ¿Será una regla anterior que se ha abandonado?  ¿Sigue en vigencia?

Answer (score 6):

Puede haber ocasiones en las que una coma preceda a la conjunción *y*, @Mike menciona algunas en su respuesta, pero en el caso de las enumeraciones no es correcto.

En la web de [wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Coma#Enumeraciones) explica que se usa la coma entre los términos de una enumeración **excepto en los unidos por una conjunción**. Poner esa coma es lo que se denomina [coma de Oxford](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Coma_de_Oxford) y según la entrada de wikilengua de este término «no es práctica general en inglés y en español se censura».

A continuación el extracto de wikilengua que trata este tema:

> #### 1.2 Enumeraciones
>
> **1.** Se escribe coma entre los términos, simples o compuestos, de una enumeración, excepto los unidos por conjunción. Se considera
> anglicismo ortográfico colocar, en estos casos, una coma seguida de
> una conjunción.
>
> ```
> Todos vinieron a la fiesta: Pedro, Juan, María, César y Cristina.  
>
> ⊗Todos vinieron a la fiesta: Pedro, Juan, María, César, y Cristina.
> ```
>
> Esta coma se llama a menudo *coma de Oxford*.

Comment: En especifico la coma oxsford es del idioma Ingles y personalmente creo que no debe ser utilizada en el español, su uso es considerado in anglisismo.

Comment: @Mike por eso la frase con coma tiene una [bolaspa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5mcb0kS), porque no es correcto. En una enumeración no se pone coma antes de la conjunción

Comment: por eso le di el voto positive, pero crei que era necesario comentar que su uso no era apropiado en español

Comment: De acuerdo con @Mike, de la respuesta tal y como está no queda del todo claro si es correcto o no. Y no todo el mundo conoce que ⊗ = incorrecto. Quizás podrías matizar un poco la respuesta?

Comment: Ok. Intentaré explicarlo mejor

Answer (score 5):

> ¿En ocasiones debe usarse coma antes de “y”?

Sí, en ocasiones debe usarse coma antes de "y". No en el ejemplo que das, ni usando la regla que mencionas, pero en otros casos sí.

### ¿Cuándo NO se debe usar coma antes de "y"?

Ya en otras respuestas y comentarios se menciona, pero acá dejo lo que dice la [**RAE**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=V1EqcYbX4D61AWBBrd)  al respecto:

> El uso de la coma es incompatible con las conjunciones *y*, *e*, *ni*, *o*, *u* cuando este signo se utiliza para separar elementos de una misma serie o miembros gramaticalmente equivalentes dentro de un mismo enunciado.

Con la última frase de esa explicación se descarta el ejemplo que colocas, porque tenemos varios elementos de una misma serie además de la conjunción "y".

> Tengo cinco crayones: rojo, verde, azul, amarillo, y naranja. [incorrecto]

Con esto podemos decir que:

> si un listado tiene más de tres elementos debe colocarse una coma antes de la "y"

es una regla que no es cierta.

### ¿Cuándo SÍ se debe usar coma antes de "y"?

El mismo enlace de la RAE explica los casos en los que la coma antes de "y" (y las otras conjunciones mencionadas:  *e*, *ni*, *o*, *u*) es necesaria:

*Énfasis mío*

> Sin embargo, hay otros casos en que **no solo** el uso conjunto de la coma y la conjunción es **admisible**, **sino necesario**:
>
> 2.1. En una relación compuesta de elementos complejos que se separan unos de otros por punto y coma, delante de la conjunción que introduce el último de ellos se escribe una coma (o también un punto y coma; → punto y coma, 3a): *En el armario colocó la vajilla; en el cajón, los cubiertos; en los estantes, los vasos, y los alimentos, en la despensa*.
>
> 2.2. Se escribe coma delante de estas conjunciones cuando la secuencia que encabezan enlaza con todo el predicado anterior, y no con el último de sus miembros coordinados:
>
> *Pagó el traje, el bolso y los zapatos, y salió de la tienda.*
>
> 2.3. Cuando se enlazan miembros gramaticalmente equivalentes dentro de un mismo enunciado, si el último de ellos es semánticamente heterogéneo con respecto a los anteriores (es decir, no introduce un elemento perteneciente a la misma serie o enumeración), por indicar normalmente una conclusión o una consecuencia, se escribe coma delante de la conjunción: *Pintaron las paredes de la habitación, cambiaron la disposición de los muebles, pusieron alfombras nuevas, y quedaron encantados con el resultado*.
>
> 2.4. Es frecuente, aunque no obligatorio, que entre oraciones coordinadas se ponga coma delante de la conjunción cuando la primera tiene cierta extensión y, especialmente, cuando tienen sujetos distintos: *La mujer salía de casa a la misma hora todas las mañanas, y el agente seguía sus pasos sin levantar sospechas*; ....
>
> 2.5. Cuando la conjunción y tiene valor adversativo (equivalente a pero), puede ir precedida de coma: *Le aconsejé que no comprara esa casa, y no hizo caso*.
>
> 2.6. Debe escribirse coma delante o detrás de cualquiera de estas conjunciones si inmediatamente antes o después hay un inciso o cualquier otro elemento que deba ir aislado por comas del resto del enunciado: *Mi abuelo, que era un gran aficionado a la poesía, y el maestro del pueblo fundaron una revista literaria*...

Comment: The lengthy quote from the RAE goes beyond the specifics of the question which was about lists so perhaps you might want to point that out? Leave it all in of course as it is very informative about the more general question.

Answer (score 3):

[En un blog llamado "ecoescritura"](http://ecoescritura.com/coma-antes-de-la-y/)  hay algunos ejemplos de casos en los que la coma se puede utilizar antes de una `y`:

- Se pone coma delante de y cuando alguna de las oraciones coordinadas tiene distinto sujeto o la primera tiene cierta extensión:

  > Lleva toda la vida trabajando en distintos puestos de la construcción, y ahora nadie quiere darle un empleo.
- Se escribe coma delante de estas conjunciones cuando la secuencia que encabezan no enlaza con el último de los miembros coordinados, sino con toda la proposición anterior:

  > Se pasó el día leyendo, jugando y bebiendo, y al día siguiente tenía una resaca increíble.
- Cuando en una relación de miembros gramaticalmente equivalentes, el último de ellos indica una conclusión o una consecuencia:

  > Fueron al cine, comieron una hamburguesa, compraron ropa y zapatos, y aún así no mejoró su estado de ánimo.
- Cuando la conjunción y tiene valor adversativo (equivalente a pero):

  > No podía comer dulces, y los comió.
- Cuando se repite la conjunción ante cada uno de los miembros coordinados (polisíndeton), se puede escribir (o no) comas entre todos ellos:

  > Es tan guapo, y tan listo, y tan cariñoso, y tan generoso, y huele tan bien, y me quiere tanto…
- En una relación de elementos separados por punto y coma, el último, ante el que aparece la conjunción copulativa, puede ir precedido indistintamente de coma o punto y coma.

  > En el armario verde guarda los abrigos; en el blanco, las camisetas; en la cómoda azul, la ropa interior, y en el altillo, las cosas que no utiliza con frecuencia.
- Cuando inmediatamente detrás de alguna de estas conjunciones viene cualquier elemento que deba aparecer aislado por comas:

  > Su padre, que es más bien tímido, y mi tío se pueden pasar horas sin hablar.
- También se escribe coma delante de estas conjunciones cuando la secuencia que introducen supone especificaciones o aclaraciones a modo de inciso:

  > No para de hablar con una voz clara y segura, y eso que no sabía bien ni lo que tenía ni decir, pero ese hombre parece tener el arte de la oratoria.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70643/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-en-ocasiones-debe-usarse-coma-antes-de-y). Relevant Meta discussion: [When the line between nice and not nice is fuzzy](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2758/1674)